# Kotlinx Serializer for List<T> instead of just T at Serializable annotation of field

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization, kotlinx

So I have this class to for Json deserialization:

```
@Serializable
data class NetworkUser(
    @SerialName("id")
    val id: Long,

    ...

    @Serializable(RoleSerializer::class)
    @SerialName("role")
    val role: List<Role>
)
```

Serializer for `Role` Enum class:

```
object RoleSerializer : KSerializer<Role> {
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Role =
        Role.valueOf(decoder.decodeString())

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor(
        serialName = "Instant",
        kind = PrimitiveKind.STRING,
    )

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Role) =
        encoder.encodeString(value.name)
}
```

But I get this error

[image]

How can I use it with `List<Role>` instead of just `Role`? I don't really want to create another `KSerializer` just for parsing a list, it is boilerplate code

In my case I need it for Android Retrofit Json parsing, if I need to create two `KSerializer` for object and list of objects then I better return back `Gson` serialization and `TypeAdapters`, you only create a Type Adapter for object once with Gson, no need to create it for lists, also you don't need to add annotation to every field where it's used

Comment: Where is `Role` defined? Could you annotate it with `@Serializable(with = RoleSerializer::class)` to bind your custom serializer to it? Otherwise, could you try one of the suggestions in the docs for [serializing 3rd party classes](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/v1.5.0/docs/serializers.md#serializing-3rd-party-classes)?

Comment: @aSemy by the link I didn't find any examples with list and annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

`@SerialName("role") val role: List<@Serializable(with = RoleSerializer::class) Role>`

Comment: yeah, already found that time, forgot to answer here